# Error Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object when saving to database

Tags: magento-1.9, model

I am at a loss, I've tried a lot of stuff but nothing seems to work to get rid of this error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object in /home1/powertg2/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 313
```

What I am trying to accomplish it to submit an RFQ form with simple data and save results to a database.

Power/Rfq/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Power_Rfq>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Power_Rfq>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <rfq>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Power_Rfq</module>
                <frontName>submit-rfq</frontName>
            </args>
        </rfq>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <submitrfq>
                <file>rfq.xml</file>
            </submitrfq>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <models>
        <rfq>
            <class>Power_Rfq_Model</class>
            <ressourceModel>rfq_mysql4</ressourceModel>
        </rfq>
        <rfq_mysql4>
            <class>Power_Rfq_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <submitrfq>
                    <table>submitrfq</table>
                </submitrfq>
            </entities>
        </rfq_mysql4>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <rfq_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Power_Rfq</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </rfq_setup>
    </resources>

    <helpers>
        <rfq>
            <class>Power_Rfq_Helper</class>
        </rfq>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Power/Rfq/controller/IndexController.php

```
// Save the customer to the database
$rfq = Mage::getModel('rfq/submitrfq');
$rfq->setData('first_name', $post['first_name']);
// Other set data

$rfq->save();
```

Power/Rfq/Model/Submitrfq.php

```
class Power_Rfq_Model_Submitrfq extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('rfq/submitrfq');
    }
}
```

Power/Rfq/Model/Mysql4/Submitrfq.php

```
class Power_Rfq_Model_Mysql4_Submitrfq extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('rfq/submitrfq', 'submitrfq_id');
    }
}
```

Power/Rfq/Model/Mysql4/Submitrfq/Collection.php

```
class Power_Rfq_Model_Mysql4_Submitrfq_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('rfq/submitrfq');
    }
}
```

This is for Magento 1.9. I am able to call other Model functions like getCollections(); but this one just isn't working.

Any and all help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Ok well the French in me came out.

```
<ressourceModel>rfq_mysql4</ressourceModel>
```

To change to

```
<resourceModel>rfq_mysql4</resourceModel>
```